# How to connect to database using an applet

Tags: java, database, applet

I created a java swing applet and inserted it in to a web page but I can't connect to the database through the web page how can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: [Can you post some code that you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: It depends. How are you connecting to the database? Does your applet have the required permissions to achieve it (ability to open sockets for example)

Comment: Are you sure you even want to open your database to arbitrary outside connections from client-side applets? That means the applet will know your database credentials, which is very insecure.

Comment: @AndrewMao  +1.  The applet should not have direct access to the DB if it being 'let loose' on the internet.  If the app. is not being deployed on the internet, it should not be an applet.  I doubt there is a convincing case where an applet *should* have direct access to a DB.

Answer (score 3):

You're facing several things here:

- your applet by design can't connect to any resources except those hosted on the same host as the applet itself
- your applet when run directly from a webbrowser (so not called from an http server but loading the html page it sits in from your harddisk) has no host so can't connect to anything at all
- as mentioned in comments, having an applet contain account information for a database (or indeed anything) is a massive security risk
- not even mentioning scalability concerns here, at your level of competence you'll not run into problems with that as not enough people will ever access your applet (no insult intended, but if you don't know this you're not going to be working for a high traffic website as they'd never have hired you)

  Best thing to do is have the applet call a servlet using HTTP calls, then have the servlet do the database work and return the results to the applet, NOT the ResultSet or other JDBC entities, but turn the result into something like an XML document or CSV and send that back in the HTTP response.

Answer (score -1):

The database code is below:

```
Class.forName("Driver Name");//example Driver Name="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcBridge" if your are using ODBC Driver

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("Connection String");
```

Comment: his problem is not the code to create the connection, but the whole shebang of security implications of having an applet connect to a database.